# Is there a way to make an ASP.NET POST method work without a model as a param?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here's my method now:

```
    public class UserTestAdminTestId
    {
        public int AdminTestId { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Post")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserTestAdminTestId userTestAdminTestId)
```

There's more code inside of the Post Method and the only data I need for it is the AdminTestId.

I made a model (class) to accept this but assuming that I send the AdminTestId as a JSON object, is there a way for me to tell the post method what to expect without creating a class for just one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it will have to be a nullable int.

Keep in mind though that your body is only bound to one variable so if you have multiple values, you'll have to group them in a single type.

Comment: Can you show me how I can do this?  I do only need to send the one value to the method as the method takes this and creates an object based on this single value.

Comment: just turn it into `Post([FromBody] int? adminTestId)`

Comment: Okay that looks pretty good. I didn't realize it was so simple.  So just to clarify, are you saying that I can only do this if I want to bring across one value and I cannot do it for more than one?

Comment: Yes, exactly; The body of a request will be bound to a single variable: if it's just an int you can use the `int?` directly in your method definition but if there are more fields then you have to group them.